# Comparing Negative Indices in Numpy with Postive Indices

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, indices, modular-arithmetic

I have a numpy array of indeterminate size and I need to compare some indices being used to extract data. For example if `start_index > end_index` I want an error to be thrown. However, sometimes the indices might be negative, most notably we might have `end_index = -1` to represent the final element in the array. If I just straight up compared the indices and `end_index` was negative an error could be thrown incorrectly.

My current solution is to check if `start_index % array_length > end_index % array_length`.

This does work, but I'm now having to think about everything using modular arithmetic. Does anyone know of a more efficient solution, perhaps a tool from numpy itself?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use modular arithmetic, you could simply convert negative indices to their positive equivalent before checking.  It might be a bit more intuitive, although honestly either method looks fine.  You could also just use a `try/except` to catch these errors and just throw indices at it.  I'd recommend the latter since then you don't have to bother checking for array length either

Comment: Would `try/except` really work? I know that I can set all of my indices to be non-negative, but this code will be further developed and used by other people. So I want it to be rather robust and able to check for and handle these things. I want to  be able to work with negative indices but explain what's happening if `start_index > end_index` accounting for negatives.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that the check is done when the indices are first set, they're actually used later in the code.

Comment: If all you're doing is making sure that that `start_index <= end_index`, you could do something like `array[start_index:end_index].size >= 0`, where `array` is a 1D Numpy array. For N-dimensional arrays you'd use something like `array[<selection-using-start-and-end-indicies>].shape[dimension] >= 0`

Comment: That does sound like an interesting idea. However mightn't the size be 0 for reasons other than `start_index` being larger than `end_index`?